# ionic - ios-deploy - Could not receive a message from the device

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, deployment, npm, updates

I think I updated ios-deploy and broke something. I updated from 1.9.1 to 1.9.2 and now I get this (I'm not sure if this is why I am getting an error it just correlates):

```
------ Debug phase ------
Starting debug of 2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356 (N51AP, iPhone 5s (GSM), iphoneos, arm64) a.k.a. 'Eamon White’s iPhone' connected through USB...
[  0%] Looking up developer disk image
[ 90%] Mounting developer disk image
[ 95%] Developer disk image already mounted
2017-10-07 19:03:37.672 ios-deploy[11915:3408295] [ !! ] Error 0xe800002e: Could not receive a message from the device. AMDeviceLookupApplications(device, options, &result)
Error: Error code 253 for command: ios-deploy with args: --justlaunch,--no-wifi,-d,-b,/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myapp/platforms/ios/build/device/myApp.app


[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run ios (exit code 1).
```

I have tried to revert to 1.9.1 but it won't let me install, it gives me an error:

```
ld: framework not found MobileDevice
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/Release/ios-deploy normal x86_64
(1 failure)
npm ERR! Darwin 17.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.7.3/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ios-deploy@1.9.1"
npm ERR! node v7.7.3
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! ios-deploy@1.9.1 preinstall: `./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 65
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ios-deploy@1.9.1 preinstall script './src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ios-deploy package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ios-deploy
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ios-deploy
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/eamonwhite/Downloads/ionicmane-master/npm-debug.log
```

Also, before this started happening, it randomly started hanging on the splashscreen for iOS and never receiving the deviceready signal.

Answer (score 0):

sudo npm install --global --unsafe-perm ios-deploy

Comment: Would you care to elaborate what this command does and why it helps to solve the problem at hand? Thanks.